# Rails Form is being submitted automatically when I visit page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation, submit

I have a rating form with 5 radios and a submit button in it. The problem is when I visit this page, for some reason it tries to submit the form (with 'zero' values, of course). Validations don't let to do this, so it renders error message, which is not pretty.

**Rating form:**

```
= simple_form_for @shop.ratings.find_or_create_by(user_id: user_id), 
                                    :html => {:id => form_id, 
                                    :class => "star_rating_form"} do |f|
  = f.hidden_field :shop_id, :value => @shop.id
  - if signed_in?
    = f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id
  = f.input :stars, 
      :label => "", 
      :collection => [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]], 
      :label_method => :last, 
      :value_method => :first,
      :as => :radio_buttons, 
      :item_wrapper_class => 'inline',
      :checked => true
  = f.submit
```

**Ratings controller:**

```
class RatingsController < InheritedResources::Base
  belongs_to :shop
  actions :create, :update

  def create
    @shop = Shop.find(params[:rating][:shop_id])
    super
  end

  def update
    @shop = Shop.find(params[:rating][:shop_id])
    super
  end

  private

    def permitted_params
      params.permit(:rating => [:stars])
    end
```

I tried to do like `super unless params[:rating][:stars] == 0` however, it didn't help.

PS For the rest the form works fine.

Comment: I am not sure but is this bcoz you are using `find_or_create_by` which is right away creating object, try find_or_initialize_by. Or look in javascript somewhere you specified `function onload() {
  form.submit();
}` is specified. Hope it may help

Comment: @Sontya, thanks! The one with find_or_initialize_by was the answer! Post it, and I'll submit it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure but is this bcoz you are using find_or_create_by which is right away creating object, try find_or_initialize_by. Or look in javascript somewhere you specified function onload() { form.submit(); } is specified. Hope it may help